# Limits of transcendental functions by direct substitution (rigorous proofs)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

> **Question:** Does anyone know of a good source (book, web, etc.) that rigorously proves the limits below (could use infinite series representations of trig functions, $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments, whatever)? I haven't been able to find anything in any of the standard calculus texts and didn't see anything in Rudin either. Maybe Spivak? Any reference would be greatly appreciated.

In a popular calculus text by Larson, the following shows up in a section about evaluating limits analytically:

[image]

I've seen a couple of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs, for instance, that $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x=0$ or something similar but nothing like what appears above. Presumably, the author is taking advantage of the continuity of the listed transcendental functions without explicitly saying so. I find the "presented without proof" piece to be rather frustrating.

Comment: A rigorous textbook will say it differently,  For example, fact 4 is stated: the function $\cot$ is continuous.  (That is probably why you did not find such formulas stated in Rudin.)  I guess Larson states it without proof because such proofs belong in a "real analysis" course.  Even Larson may have a theorem: if the derivative exists, then it is continuous.  And later on, proofs that these functions are differentiable.

Comment: @GEdgar It's very possible that I simply missed it, but I did not see anything in Rudin on this. There was nothing in the chapter on continuity and there wasn't much relevant in the chapter on "special functions" of which the trig functions play a sizable role.

Comment: So you claim that Rudin never proved that $\sin$ is continuous, or that $\sin$ is differentiable (which implies continuous)?  That would have been a grave omission on his part!

Comment: @GEdgar He must have, but I just can't spot the relevant portion(s). His treatment of trig functions in the "special functions" chapter is very brief (~ 2 pages) and not geometric. I found [this](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/TransContinuityProofs08.htm) which looks decent at first glance but will try to find some references from more reputable sources. Thanks for the reference though.

Comment: It's saddening to learn that in a "widespread calculus text" such bullshit theorems like the Theorem 2.6 appear. The essential facts are the following: Sine and the others, by any definition, are continuous functions. For such functions the limit is obtained by "plugging in".

Comment: It is better to prove such theorems in any elementary calculus text since the proofs are easy. And then we have the generalization that any elementary function is continuous wherever it is defined. You may consult either Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics* or Spivak's *Calculus* for the proofs of these results. Rudin may have also handled this but Rudin's book is boring.